# Symfony2 use NotFoundException message

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 2 you can do the following to return a 404 page

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('message');
```

I was assuming that `status_text` in the error template would display the custom message, but that does not seem to be the case. How can you display the custom message?

*Short question, but I dont think this needs more information? Feel free to ask!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [`show` action](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBundle/blob/master/Controller/ExceptionController.php#L48) of `ExceptionController` you can access the exception inside twig:

```
{{ exception.message }}
```

`status_text` and `status_code` are related to the HTTP protocol. To customize the error page look at [the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, nothing in the documentation about how to use the message, thanks a lot. Wasn't sure how to look it up.